# How to create DLL project in VS2017 correctly?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and I want to create a C++ dll.library. I use the following manual:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms235636.aspx

However there is no manual for VS 2017, only for 2015 and below. VS 2017 haven't project type Win32 Console Application and it doesn't open Win32 Application Wizard dialog box.

How I can create C++ DLL project in VS2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create the DLL project:**

In this set of tasks, you create a project for your DLL, add code, and build it. To begin, start the Visual Studio IDE, and sign in if you need to. The instructions for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 come first. Instructions for earlier versions come later, so skip ahead if you need to.

To create a **DLL** project in *Visual Studio 2017* version 15.3 or later

1. On the menu bar, choose File, New, Project to open the New Project
   dialog box.
2. In the left pane of the New Project dialog box, expand Installed and
       Visual C++ if required, and then choose Windows Desktop. In the center pane, select Windows Desktop Wizard. Enter MathLibrary in the
       Name box to specify a name for the project.

[image]

3. Choose the OK button to dismiss the New Project dialog and start the
   Windows Desktop Project wizard.
4. In the Windows Desktop Project wizard, under Application type,
   select Dynamic Link Library (.dll).

[image]

5. Choose the OK button to create the project.

And To use this .dll in a client app follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2017#create-a-client-app-that-uses-the-dll).